# onClick button inside RecyclerView works for multiple view instead of itself

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm writing an app to translate words.There are about 40 words in one `RecyclerView`.There is one button for each word that shows the meaning of that word.
I wrote `onClickListener` for that button inside `onBindViewHolder` like below:

```java
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final int pos = position;
        holder.tv_wordText.setText(words.get(pos).getWord());
        holder.tv_meaningText.setText(words.get(pos).getMeaning());

        holder.btn_showAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.tv_meaningText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.btn_showAnswer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```

But when I click on that button, it reveals not only itself meaning, it reveals next every 5 words. For example, if I click on the first word it revealed `1,6,11,16,21` and so on. Second button also revealed `2,7,12,17,22`. All other parts of app working correctly but that button doesn't work correctly and idk why?. I also did it inside `ViewHolder` class but works the same. Is there a way to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days I found a tricky code that works for me.
I realize that every time I scroll `RecyclerView`, codes inside `onBindViewHolder` run for every `ViewHolder` inside `RecyclerView` that comes visible. So I decide to put inside `onBindViewHolder` a code that hides that element:

```java
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final int pos = position;
        holder.tv_wordText.setText(words.get(pos).getWord());
        holder.tv_meaningText.setText(words.get(pos).getMeaning());
        holder.tv_meaningText_cv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        
        holder.btn_showAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.tv_meaningText_cv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```

But it makes all other elements invisible also.
**Please if you have any better solution, put it here.**

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the *recycling* behavior of the `RecyclerView`. When you scroll a view off of one edge of the screen, the system will eventually re-use that view for another position in your list of words. Since you only conditionally set the visibility of some views, whatever was last set will remain in the re-used view. So, if you click to show the meaning on one word, the next time that view is re-used you will be able to see the meaning of the new word.

With `RecyclerView`, it's a good idea to always have your data model (your `words` list) be able to fully represent your state. I don't know exactly what each element in `words` looks like, but I can see that each one has a `getWord()` and a `getMeaning()` function. I think you should add an `isMeaningVisible(): Boolean` function to this as well. Then you can have something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Word word = words.get(position);
    holder.tv_wordText.setText(word.getWord());
    holder.tv_meaningText.setText(word.getMeaning());
    holder.tv_meaningText_cv.setVisibility(word.isMeaningVisible() ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

The other question is what to do about the click on the button. I notice that in your code you have `final int pos`; this is not a good idea. `RecyclerView` allows you to insert or remove individual elements, and so the position passed to `onBindViewHolder()` can change over time. Because of this, it's best to set up click listeners inside `onCreateViewHolder()` instead.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.word_list_adapter, parent, false));

    holder.btn_showAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                Word word = words.get(position);
                word.setMeaningVisible(!word.isMeaningVisible());
                notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        }
    });

    return holder;
}
```

Comment: This works very well. But I add Ignore on top of isVisible variable inside my model because I don't want to save that state in the database. You saved me, thank you a lot.